# How to move postgresql database from one computer to another?

Tags: debian, database, postgresql

I've been created an Internet service on Debian server. I want to move all data from one server to a new one.
So, how can I move the postresql database? What is the best pipeline?

Comment: `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dump -Fc` each database, and `pg_dumpall --globals-only` the users, etc.

Run the dumpall script through `psql` to restore it. Then `pg_restore` each individual database dump.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer:
In my case 
in old machine:

```
pg_dumpall > all.tar
```

and  than in the new machine:

```
sudo -u postgres psql  < all.tar
```

helped to me.